# How to get Chinese (Simplified) when language tag is zh-CN in java?

Tags: java, .net

I have a requirement in which I need to print **Chinese (Simplified)** as the display name of language if my language tag is zh-CN. This is to avoid duplicate language and I wanted to combine below languages together.

1. zh-CN Chinese (People's Republic of China)
2. zh-SG Chinese (Singapore)

The same can be achieved in .NET using small hack

```
if(cultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "zh") {
    list.Add(cultureInfo.Parent.Name, cultureInfo.Parent.DisplayName);
}
```

How can I do the same in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
Locale currentLocale = Locale.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> language = new ArrayList<String>();

if(currentLocale.getCountry()=="zh"){
 Locale.setDefault(new Locale("zh", "CHS"));
 Locale newLocale = Locale.getDefault();
 String name = newLocale.getDisplayLanguage();
 language.add(name);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Take a look at this article.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.displayname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This snippet will give me Chinese(CHS) as DisplayName, I need to display the same as Chinese (Simplified), the same thing can be achieved in .NET

Answer (score 0):

Language and geographic regions are specified in java using Locale. With the following snippet in Java 8 , find that all locales with zh have the display language name as Chinese.

```
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
Map<Locale, String> result = Arrays.stream(locales)
                                   .filter(locale -> locale.toString().startsWith("zh"))
                                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(locale -> locale, locale -> "Chinese (Simplified)"));
System.out.println(result);
```

Output on JDK 8u121:
{zh_CN=Chinese (Simplified), zh=Chinese (Simplified), zh_HK=Chinese (Simplified), zh_TW=Chinese (Simplified), zh_SG=Chinese (Simplified)}

Comment: Thanks for responding, this snippet will give me all the chinese languages but my requirement is to categorize all chinese simplified languages and traditional languages. if locale is zh_CN, then I need to display the language name as Chinese (Simplified) instead of "Chinese(China) - China"

Comment: I just modified the snippet , hope this helps.